# How do I draw a 3D border using visual styles?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-styles

I can draw a 3D border using ControlPaint.DrawBorder3D, but I get the 'Windows Classic' 3D border.  I want to draw the current theme's 3D border - in the default XP theme, this is a 1px blue or gray border.  How do I draw that, and how do I get its widths?

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you might need to look at [System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.VisualStyleRenderer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.visualstyles.visualstylerenderer.aspx):

> The `System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles`
>   namespace exposes `VisualStyleElement`
>   objects that represent all of the
>   controls and user interface (UI)
>   elements that are supported by visual
>   styles. To draw or get information
>   about a particular element, you must
>   set a `VisualStyleRenderer` to the
>   element you are interested in.
>
> To draw an element, use the
>   `DrawBackground` method. The
>   `VisualStyleRenderer` class also
>   includes methods, such as `GetColor` and
>   `GetEnumValue`, that provide information
>   about how an element is defined by the
>   current visual style.

There's a code sample on that page as well.

You will have to draw the border yourself, but you can get the color from  `VisualStyleElement.Window.Caption.Active` and the size should be the size of the window frame (I believe), which is `VisualStyleElement.Window.FrameBottom.Active`. If you explore the `VisualStyleElement.Window`, you should be able to determine which window element has the information you need to draw your border.

Comment: Is this new to 2008 (he didn't specify which version he was using, just wondering)

Comment: Hmm, it came about with 2.0.  Much easier (if he's using at least 2.0) +1

Comment: Which VisualStyleElement do I need?  None of them look right to me.

Answer (score 1):

**Pre .NET Framework 2.0 Answer**

I'm assuming that you are drawing your own, special control and you want to use elements of the currently active theme to draw it so it better fits with standard XP controls.  You're **NOT** trying to, for example, enable theming on a standard Button control.  Correct?

It's actually somewhat complicated.  Your main focus should be UxTheme.dll.  This houses everything you need for drawing themed controls.  [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/uxtheme.aspx) is a nice C# wrapper around this dll to make your life easier.  There are others so if this isn't exactly what you wanted, I hope I've pointed you in the right direction.